# Update profile data not working asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am trying to update a simple query using web forms but to no avail. I have tried debugging the code but could not find where is the bug. There are two methods `page_load()` and `editProfile_click()` of which the code is following:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        connetionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AspNetInventory;Integrated Security=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE employeeId = @id";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Username.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                UName.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                UPhoneNo.Text = dr[4].ToString();
                Uemail.Text = dr[5].ToString();
            }
        }//try
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Username.Text = "db Connection fail" + ex;
        }
    }

    protected void SaveProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
        string username, fullName, phoneNo, Email;
        username = Convert.ToString(Username.Text);
        fullName = Convert.ToString(UName.Text);
        phoneNo = Convert.ToString(UPhoneNo.Text);
        Email = Convert.ToString(Uemail.Text);

        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection con;

        connetionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AspNetInventory;Integrated Security=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = @"UPDATE UserDetails SET userName=@UserName, Name= @fullName, phoneNo = @Phone, Email=@uEmail WHERE employeeId='" + id + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", fullName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phoneNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uEmail", Email);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }//try
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Username.Text = "db Connection fail" + ex;
        }           
    }
```

When I press the Update profile button the unchanged record from the data base gets fetched. Please tell me if there is a problem with the query.

Comment: What do you mean "gets fetched"? Do you mean you don't see the changed data on the screen? Do you reload the data after updating it? Did you pay attention to when Page_Load happens?

Comment: You need to control the Page_Load code. If you don't exclude the loading of your data when IsPostback is true you reload the code from the database everytime you click on the button [Page.IsPostBack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_Page_IsPostBack) You need to understand [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use **if(!IsPostBack){ //here is your code }** under page load  because when you click on save button it first executes page_load then save click event. Otherwise `page_load` overwrites your changes and saves.

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = @"UPDATE UserDetails SET userName=@UserName, Name= @fullName, phoneNo = @Phone, Email=@uEmail WHERE employeeId=" + id ;
```

Or :

```
string query = @"UPDATE UserDetails SET userName=@UserName, Name= @fullName, phoneNo = @Phone, Email=@uEmail WHERE employeeId=@ID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
```